# How to connect SQL developer/Toad to Oracle 8i

Tags: ide, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad, oracle8i

Please let me know if there's a way to connect SQL developer/toad to Oracle 8i version.

Currently I get unsupported Oracle version error in both the IDEs.

OR if there's any IDE that supports Oracle 8i  , please let me know

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer's support for connecting to the Oracle Database is defined by the JDBC driver we are using.

There is no version of SQL Developer today that officially supports an 8i instance of the database as the newer JDBC drivers do not support 8i.

If you look at when 8i was released, 1998, and look at when SQL Developer was released, 2005, then you can begin to understand this 'gap' of support.

[If you are desperate, you can grab version 1.2 and try that. It apparently will connect, but it will also error that you need at least version 9i.](https://community.oracle.com/thread/671137?start=15&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, 8i? Time to upgrade, don't you think?

Anyway: I don't have any 8i database available any more so I can't try it myself, but you might try with [SQLTools++ for Oracle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlt-pp/):

> SQLTools++ is a spin-off of the original SQLTools for Oracle. Like the original SQLTools SQLTools++ is a light weight and robust Windows GUI SQL frontend for Oracle databases. It works with Oracle 7.3/8/**8i**/9i/10g and 11g. Note: Oracle Client required